# Why this program output 64?

Tags: c

I found this program during an online test on c programming I tried it on my level but I cannot figure it out that why the output of this program comes out to be 64.

Can anyone explain the concept behind this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a = 320;
    char *ptr;
    ptr = (char *)&a;
    printf("%d",*ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

output:

> 64

Thankyou.

Comment: hint: what is size of char? would it fit..

Comment: `320`in hexadécimal is `0x140`. `0x40` in decimal is `64`. Anymore questions?

Comment: @MichaelWalz .. oh this way he wont learn anything :D

Comment: 'cause `0x40` is `64` decimal.... ;) BTW it totally depends on the endianness...

Comment: @otopolsky it may make him start to think and find the answer by himself.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I mean its too big spoiler

Comment: @otopolsky spoiler ? The answers are the real spoilers ;-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A `char *` points to one byte only. Assuming a byte on your system is 8 bits, the number `320` occupies 2 bytes. The lower byte of those is 64, the upper byte is 1, because `320 = 256 * 1 + 64`. That is why you get 64 on your computer (a [little-endian](https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Data/endian.html) computer).

But note that on other platforms, so called big-endian platforms, the result could just as well be `1` (the most significant byte of a 16 bit/2 byte value) or `0` (the most significant byte of a value larger than 16 bit/2 bytes).

Note that all this assumes that the platform has 8-bit bytes. If it had, say 10-bit bytes, you would get a different result again. Fortunately, most computers have 8-bit bytes nowadays.

Answer (score 5):

You won't be able to understand this unless you know about:

1. hex/binary represenation, and
2. CPU endianess.

Type out the decimal number 320 in hex. Split it up in bytes. Assuming `int` is 4 bytes, you should be able to tell which parts of the number that goes in which bytes.

After that, consider the *endianess* of the given CPU and sort the bytes in that order. (MS byte first or LS byte first.)

The code accesses the byte allocated at the lowest address of the integer. What it contains depends on the CPU endianess. You'll either get hex 0x40 or hex 0x00.

---

Note: You shouldn't use `char` for these kind of things, because it has implementation-defined signedness. In case the data bytes contains values larger than 0x7F, you might get some very weird bugs, that inconsistently appear/disappear across multiple compilers. Always use `uint8_t*` when doing any form of bit/byte manipulation.

You can expose this bug by replacing 320 with 384. Your little endian system may then either print -128 or 128, you'll get different results on different compilers.

Comment: The code does not access the most significant byte, but the one of the four bytes stored in memory with smallest address - which can either be the most or least significant one.

Comment: @Aconcagua Indeed, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

`Int` is `four` byte data byte while `char` is one byte data byte, char pointer can keep the address one byte at time. Binary value of `320` is `00000000 00000000 00000001 01000000`. So, `char pointer` `ptr` is pointing to only `first byte`.
`*ptr` i.e. content of first byte is `01000000` and its decimal value is `64`.

Answer (score 0):

What @Lundin said is enough.
BTW, maybe some basic knowledge is helpful. 320 = 0x0140. a int = 4 char. So when print the first byte, it output 0x40 = 64 because of cpu endianess.

Comment: This is technically incorrect; int is four chars only on the most common processors these days. But especially micro controllers and DSP can differ, saw int = 16 bit = 2 char and even int = 16 bit = 1 char.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! My fault, I just want to write something easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

ptr is char pointer of a. Thus *ptr will give char value of a. char occupies only 1 byte thus it repeats its values after 255. That is 256 becomes 0, 257 becomes 1 and so on. Thus 320 becomes 64.